# Не справиться as an idiom

Tags: выражения, идиомы, infinitive-sentence

"Только силой с этим явлением [terrorism] **не справиться**, тем более, что смерть террористов не пугает".

I was intrigued at the usage of the infinitive ***справиться*** here. Normally the third person plural is used in order to express an impersonal subject (like "говорят..." in the sense of "it is told that...").

But, apparently, "не справиться" translates here as *"one can't cope with"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Не справиться** here can be thought of as a short form for **не**(-льзя/-возможно) **справиться**. So yes, your translation is correct while a more literal one would sound like *'it's impossible to cope with (to overwhelm/overcome)...'*

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not an idiom, it's one of grammatical vehicles to express *inability*, constructed as

**Dative + negated (perfective) infinitive**

In positive statements, which express *ability*, either the inflected modal verb **мочь** is employed or the inflected adjective **способен**

Compare:

**Мне не поднять этот камень** VS **Я могу/способен поднять этот камень**

A positive expression of *ability* similar to that of *inability* requires for example addition of adverbial phrases ***под силу; по плечу*** if it's about physical or intellectual ability or ***по средствам; по карману*** if it's about financial ability

**Мне не поднять этот камень** VS **Мне под силу поднять этот камень**

However their use is context dependent.