# Why does "скрыться" take the infinitive form in "От меня так просто не скрыться!"?

Tags: грамматика, infinitive-sentence

> От меня так просто не **скрыться**!

I wonder why you can omit the second-person singular/plural "сможешь/сможете" and just use the infinitive "скрыться" here?

> {vs}: От меня так просто не **сможешь/сможете** скрыться!

Comment: You can think of **не** as an abbreviation of **не**льзя (impossible to...) here.

Answer (score 4):

This is called either [*an independent infinitive construction*](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC#214) (конструкция с независимым инфинитивом) or [*an infinitive sentence*](https://moluch.ru/archive/69/11950/) (инфинитивное предложение)

The nuts and bolts have been explained, hopefully satisfactorily, at [**Не справиться as an idiom**](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/16429/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-as-an-idiom)

> Инфинитивные предложения с отрицательной частицей ***не*** выражают
>   такие отрицательные модальные значения как: а) невозможность,
>   b) невыполнимость, c) ненужность и d) запрещение совершения действия. В
>   школьной грамматике отдельное выделение инфинитивных предложений
>   отсутствует, они считаются одним из видов безличных.
>
> По словам Д. Э. Розенталя *«Инфинитивными предложениями* называются
>   односоставные предложения, в которых главный член выражен *независимым
>   инфинитивом*» [11, с. 79]. Он считает, что инфинитивные предложения –
>   это особая разновидность односоставных предложений. **Обязательный
>   компонент в структуре русских инфинитивных предложений – это
>   *независимый инфинитив*, для которого структурно-обязательным является дательный субъект, т. е. форма дательного падежа со значением
>   субъекта действия**.

<sup>*Барари Р., Мадаэни А. А. Инфинитивные предложения с отрицательным значением в русском языке и способы их выражения в персидском // Молодой ученый. — 2014. — №10. — С. 522-527*</sup>

> **значение невозможности требует совершенного вида глагола**.
>   Исключения –
>   *не видать*, *не жить*
>   Употребление несовершенного вида облегчается также в контексте *больше не*: *После
>   такой операции `не летать вам больше`*

Comment: @V.V. это для изучающих русский язык, если кто попросит - переведу, не могу не отметить вашу вежливость

Comment: Your answer is great, but a bit hard for the beginners, sorry if it was rude, no offence meant.

Comment: @V.V. judging by the content of his questions, Alone-zee's understanding of Russian is already pretty advanced, so this is a reply with a challenge for anyone who's willing to take it, but i didn't bother to translate also because there's a reference to another topic with a detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

The 1st phrase emphasises impersonality slightly, implying noone can get away from "me": "It's not so easy [for anyone] to get away from me".

The 2nd one requires pronoun or noun, and so gets somewhat specific in meaning: "YOU won't (be able to) get away from me so easily".

Comment: Also, the second one pushes to move "so easily"/"так просто" to the end of the sentence. Granted, it still might be positioned before the 1st verb or in between two verbs, but the most natural words order would be pushing it to the end. I am trying to rationalize the practical difference between [ can (get away easily) ] and [ easily can (get away) ] - and it seems to be minuscule if ever present. Still the words order would make the difference for sounding natural or abnormal.

Comment: Both orderings -- "...так просто не скрыться" and "...не скрыться так просто" -- are "normal". Here there's no explicit or widely-agreed-upon difference in the meaning just because of the words' order.

Comment: I referred to the latter phrase with TWO verbs: `От меня (1) не сможешь/сможете (2) скрыться (3)!` and `так просто` can get put into any of the three (not both=two) positions.

Comment: There are *three* orderings, then, as close in explicit meaning as makes no difference.